# Getting the id for "No data found rows" in the Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

While querying for some of the `ID` in the table there are no rows.

How do I write pl/sql to get all those `ID`'s

```
select type_id from table1 where  pid = 123;

if type_id is null then
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error ID'|| 123)
END
```

this doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know the list of IDs? Do you select them from another table?

Comment: It is selected from another table is being queried on the another table.

Comment: So in this case you can do something like: select pid from table2 where pid not in (select pid from table1)

Comment: pl/sql is looping through a cursor and this is how it looks like                    `select type_id into y from prefs where p_id = emrec._id;
             if  y <> 0 then
                update prefs set type_id = y where prospect_id = i;
              end if; `

Answer (score 1):

What is your datatype for typeid?

Assuming it is varchar2,
Try this:

```
    DECLARE
    v_type_id VARCHAR2(1000);

    begin
      select type_id INTO v_type_id from table1 where  pid = 123;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Type Id is'|| v_type_id);

    EXCEPTION

     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error ID'|| 123);
   END
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use an OUTER JOIN:

```
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT p.PID
                 FROM PROCESSES p
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 t1
                   ON t1.PID = p.PID
                 WHERE p.PID = 123 AND
                       t1.TYPE_ID IS NULL)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error ID=' || aRow.PID);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.